# Examples for predict.FAMD?

Tags: r, unsupervised-learning, pca

I am doing a study on unsupervised data with various categorical variables. So I have found the FactoMineR package to be really handy for this, particularly with the FAMD functions. I can get to a base FAMD object just fine (and the corresponding charts) but I can't seem to get the predict.FAMD side working. Are there any working examples out there? Here's what I've done:

1. I have a mix of continuous and categorical data
2. I have split the data into a test and training set
3. I have created a FAMD object with my training set
4. I try to run predict.FAMD against the test set data but I keep on getting an an error of `Error in [.data.frame(newdata, , i) : undefined columns selected`

Generally, my code looks like:

```
library(FactoMineR)
res = FAMD(myTrainingData)
res.predict = predict(object=res,newdata=myTestData)
```

I've also tried variations on explicit columns and even no rows, like:

```
res.predict = predict(object=res,newdata=myTestData[,1:7])
res.predict = predict(object=res,newdata=myTestData[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)])
res.predict = predict(object=res,newdata=myTestData[0,1:7])
```

All of these result in the same error. Help?

Comment: have exactly the same issue. it works on another machine though ... so it may be r version dependent?

Comment: yes i think it depends on the package version